# Indexing and \footcite prenotes

Tags: biblatex, indexing, xindy

I am indexing a big latex project (with xindy). I use biblatex for the bibliography and the command \footcite for the references.

Sometimes, I write long prenotes which contain some words to be indexed. The logical procedure is to put the index command before of after the \footcite command and not in the prenote. But in practice as my prenotes are very long it's sometimes difficult to notice the square backets of the prenote... And it causes a lots of bug during the compilation.

For example :

```
\footcite[blabla blabla\index[n]{something} blabla.][postnote]{Reference}
```

It takes a lot of work to correct all the errors. But maybe there is a trick to bypass compilation bugs or loose less time.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do something against square brackets causing errors in square brackets if they are not escaped without changing a lot of very deep things in LaTeX. You will just have to wrap your `\index[n]{something}` in additional curly braces `\footcite[blabla blabla{\index[n]{something}} blabla.][postnote]{Reference}`. (I would expect that to work). If your prenotes get very long though, I would suggest you rather put it into a normal footnote: `\footnote{blabla blabla\index[n]{something} blabla. \cite[post]{referefce}}`. In my book the prenote is for short pre-notes only.

Comment: @moewe: I suspect your proposition to work. `[]` inside `[]` must be 'protected' or escaped with `{}` Perhaps you should try an answer?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer So do I `;-)`. But I wasn't too sure if maybe in `biblatex`'s footnotes indexing is inhibited for some reason. And since I can't do any proper testing, I just expect it to work.

Comment: Yes it works! I will substitute my \index[n]{something} by {\index[n]{something}} from now ! Thanks!